# Apply function to remove columns R

Tags: r, apply

I have a large data frame.  I need to go through and test the first row of values and remove the columns if the value in the first row isn't below a certain threshold.

```
red <- c(1,2,3)
blue <- c(4, 5, 4)
colors <- data.frame(red, blue)
colors <- t(colors)
colors
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
red     1    2    3
blue    4    5    4
```

How would I, for example, keep only columns that have a red value below 2.5?

Thanks so much!  Im still pretty new to this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
> colors[,colors['red',] < 2.5]
     [,1] [,2]
red     1    2
blue    4    5
```

Where you don't use an `apply` function, but vectorization in stead. The expression `colors['red',] < 2.5` leads to an logical vector (`TRUE`, `FALSE`) with `TRUE` where the expression is valid, and `FALSE` where it is not. You can use this logical vector to index `colors`, where using `colors[, logical_vector]` ensures you use the logical vector to index columns.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
> colors[,colors[1, ]<2.5 ]
     [,1] [,2]
red     1    2
blue    4    5
```